# Simple mongodb search with python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a very small script that's trying to find some docs in mongodb where a certain field has today's date.

To me, as a noob, it looks like I have a good connection - but I get no results.

Wondering if it has something to do with my date formatting?

Here's my script:

```
import pymongo
from datetime import date

thedate = date.today().isoformat()

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client["hotels"]
collection = db["grand_native_test"]

query = {"skaptdato": {"$gt": thedate} }

doit = collection.find(query)

print(query)
print(collection)

for x in doit:
    print(x)
```

And the result is simply:

```
{'skaptdato': {'$gt': '2019-05-30'}}
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), u'hotels'), u'grand_native_test')
```

I've spent like 4 hours on this, really basic, script - but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

BTW: Running mongodb 3.6.3, the latest pymongo-release and python 2.7.15.

BTW-2: The formatting of the db-fields also includes minutes and seconds --> 2019-05-30 13:54:00.645Z ...

I sure hope one of you smart folks have a hint for a poor noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is in data types. For example, the DB's field contains `ISODate` type and compare with `string` type. Use the next code for `MongoDB`:

```
{skaptdato: {'$gt': ISODate('2019-05-30')}}
```

Use the next code for `pymongo`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
...
your_date_string = '2019-05-30'
date_string_to_date = datetime.strptime(your_date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
...
{'skaptdato': {'$gt': date_string_to_date}}
```

Comment: Sounds sensible. But this only throws this error: 
    NameError: name 'ISODate' is not defined

Comment: O, it's my fault. ISODate for mongoDD, datetime for python